I can't use Area3D's _Input event with subviewport as parent class
I need to access the _Input(InputEvent @event) event of an Area3D node, whose parent class is subviewport.
I used handle_input_locally = true and the parent classes set mouse filter = ignore, but still can't use the mouse event. Can someone help me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
